# Kafka foreachRDD Error when working in Spark with Avro serialization

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

I am using the example from:

http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/03/04/kafka-spark-avro-producing-and-consuming-avro-messages.html

and receiving a error with the `foreachRDD`. I have updated the java to use `lamda` expressions.

[image: Kafka foreachRDD Error]

I was wondering if you had any insight into why this would occur.

I have a program to already `deserialize` the `avro` with :

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteData);
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
        DataFileStream<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileStream<GenericRecord>(inputStream, datumReader);
```

as per my previous question [Kafka Avro Consumer with Decoder issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022358/kafka-avro-consumer-with-decoder-issues)

would it be better to just use `spark` parallelize for this data?, is that efficient after reading it from `kafka`?

Comment: @miguno I let the leadership here know about the benefits of confluents schemaRegistry and they are going to incorporate it in our configuration.

Comment: Not sure this solves your problem, but I had to ship my schemas as String to the executor, then parse them all there before doing any decoding in the executor. I couldn't figure out how to serialize the Parser, instead I create a localParser for each executor, and if it is `null` I parse all my schemas before trying to decode anything.

Comment: Thanks . I added a return null in the lamda expression and it allowed me to compile, its not a good solution but I will let you know how it goes.